# Java Regex giving only first or last match and not all of them

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm trying to get all matches with the following code:

```
 String line = ("<option value=\"001\">Values go here </option> <option value=\"002\">More values in here</option>");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"(.*)\">(.*)</option> ");
Matcher finder = p.matcher(line);
while(finder.find())
{
     System.out.println( finder.group(1));
     System.out.println( finder.group(2));
}
```

Yet I only get the last or first match. (Depending if a space is on the end or at the start of the pattern)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your regex non-greedy (lazy):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</option>");
```

OR better to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)</option>");
```

Problem in your regex is use of `.*` which is greedy and matching more text than you desired.

PS: Also note that I have remove extra space after `</option>`

Comment: Hmm I tried to make it non-greedy but just like your code it only gives me the first match.

Comment: @user3254032 Get rid of the space at the end of your pattern.

Comment: One thing to note that 2nd option will be better in case there are new lines in between and `<option>` line.